# function to create mirror image c++

Tags: c++

I have an image - 2D matrix 150 x 200 pixels:

```
PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT]
```

I have a function set up that should create a mirror image about the vertical axis. unfortunately it is not working, when I load the modified image it is still the same as the original image.

```
void MirrorImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{

    for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < HEIGHT / 2; col++)
        {
            int swapRow = WIDTH - 1 - row; // Mirror pixel

            unsigned char temp = PixelGrid[row][col];
            PixelGrid[row][col] = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];
            PixelGrid[swapRow][col] = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

I can't understand what is wrong with it, does anybody know?

Comment: I can't spot any obvious there. Did you debug that code by stepping through and check how te values change?

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with it *technically,* your variable naming will be a maintenance nightmare. `WIDTH` is the number of *columns* in an image.

Comment: @Angew Agreed I was confused there for a moment.

Comment: I just tried de-bugging it, it was taking too long and an error popped up that it may be stuck in an endless loop, would you like me to post my full code? @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @Skinkaku No, we would like you to distill a [Minimal reproducing example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your code and post *that.*

Comment: @ _" post my full code? "_ Jesh no! You provide a minimal sample that reproduces the described problem (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new on here, the function is now working anyway, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Skinkaku But you don't know why. BTW, how many accounts do you have? One for each worthless question? Is this some homework cut to parts?

Answer (score 2):

You're counting row from 0 to WIDTH when I expect you mean to do 0 to WIDTH/2?

(and col should be 0 to HEIGHT not 0 to HEIGHT/2

Answer (score 1):

Try this... It should work...

```
void MirrorImage (unsigned char PixelGrid[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{

    for (int row = 0; row < WIDTH / 2; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < HEIGHT ; col++)
        {
            int swapRow = WIDTH - 1 - row; // Mirror pixel

            unsigned char temp = PixelGrid[row][col];
            PixelGrid[row][col] = PixelGrid[swapRow][col];
            PixelGrid[swapRow][col] = temp;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome... But you had to debug this. :)